# Split Sentence in para

Tags: perl

I want split sentence in para using by perl.

Now I using Lingua::EN::Sentence module, I can split sentence without internal

```
> <em>
```

tag,  but I can't split this paragraph becuase internaly some tag

Script:

```
use strict; use Lingua::EN::Sentence qw( get_sentences add_acronyms );

$line = "En meteen is er iets. Die voorstelling dat hapert";

my $sentences = get_sentences($line); foreach my $sentence
(@$sentences) {
     print $sentence."\n"; }
```

output:

```
En meteen is er iets.
Die voorstelling dat hapert




  > <p>luk heeft aan zichzelf genoeg, het heeft geen getuigen nodig. Then
    > <em class="xix"><span class="emph-xix-brl">anna Karenina</span>.
    > </em>Ik zou daar hooguit afkunnen. Hoe meer <em>getuigen hoe<em>
    > beter. Het alleen is.</p>
```

this para how split?

Comment: You need to remove the HTML tags first...

Comment: i need split sentence without remove tag,

Comment: Then you're going to end up with mis-matched tags - `<p>A sentence.` and `Another sentence</p>` - the `<p>` tags will be mis-matched ant not valid. What happens if a sentence breaks inside an emphasised section? You'll need to manually pair up tags to result in valid html. In this case, I suspect you'll have to strip the tags, work out where the sentence breaks are, then look at the original HTML DOM and work out how to split the text at the known breakpoints while preserving tags. this seems non-trivial

Answer (score 5):

Try to use HTML::Strip to remove the tags before splitting.

***Code***

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::Strip;
use Data::Dumper;

use Lingua::EN::Sentence qw( get_sentences add_acronyms );

my $line = "En meteen is er iets. Die voorstelling dat hapert";
my $paragraph = '<p>luk heeft aan zichzelf genoeg, het heeft geen getuigen nodig. Then <em class="xix"><span class="emph-xix-brl">anna Karenina</span>.  </em>Ik zou daar hooguit afkunnen. Hoe meer <em>getuigen hoe<em>    beter. Het alleen is.</p>' ;

my $html_strip = HTML::Strip->new();
my $clean_paragraph = $html_strip->parse($paragraph);

my $sentences = get_sentences($clean_paragraph);

print Dumper($sentences);
```

***Output***

```
$VAR1 = [
      'luk heeft aan zichzelf genoeg, het heeft geen getuigen nodig.',
      'Then anna Karenina .  Ik zou daar hooguit afkunnen.',
      'Hoe meer getuigen hoe    beter.',
      'Het alleen is.'
    ];
```

Comment: This script is very useful but how can split wihtout remove internal tag,

Comment: Maybe you should specify, what your program should do and why you have to split sentences. Maybe you can parse the HTML with HTML::Tree, split senctences without HTML-Tags and then build a valid HTML-File. By the way: Lingua::EN works internally with regular expressions, which can lead to unwanted results if the text has some html code in it.